# Instantiate non-template class with templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have a small C++ class which wraps type information for some basic types; a simplified version looks like this:

```
struct TypeInfo {
    TypeInfo(std::size_t elm_size, const std::string& type_name) : 
        elm_size(elm_size), 
        type_name(type_name)
    {}

    std::size_t elm_size;
    std::string type_name;    
}


TypeInfo double_info(sizeof double, "double");
TypeInfo int_info(sizeof int, "int");
```

This works - but I would love to be able to instantiate the `TypeInfo` object based on normal C++ templating; i.e. something like this:

```
TypeInfo<double> double_info; // <- This does not work
```

Since the class as such does not contain any `T` - it is not really a templated class - but rather a convenient instantiation method. When this is contained in a function which is truly templated:

```
void vector_operation(const std::vector<T>& data) {
    TypeInfo<T> type_info;  // <- This does not work!
}
```

it would be *really* helpful if I could instantiate `TypeInfo` instance based on a template parameter. Since I only need to cover a handful of fundamental types - `float, double, int` and `char` I would be more than happy to specialize the handful of types explicitly.

**Update**: @nathan_oliver suggested to make the class as a whole a template, and then use `sizeof(T)` to determine the element size. The problem with that solution (as I see it) - is that the user still needs to supply the `type_name` string (and some more type specific information) - I would like specialize the few types I need - and then fully specify:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeInfo {
    TypeInfo();

    std::size_t elm_size;
    std::string type_name;
}
```

And then in the .cpp file:

```
template<>
TypeInfo::TypeInfo<double>() {
     this->elm_size = sizeof(double);
     this->type_name = "double";
}


template<>
TypeInfo::TypeInfo<int>() {
    this->elm_size = sizeof(int);
    this->type_name = "int";
}
```

but this does not even compile:

```
type_info.cpp:46:5: error: 
invalid use of template-name ‘TypeInfo’ without an argument list
     TypeInfo::TypeInfo()
```

Comment: You have a typo.  `TypeInfo::TypeInfo<double>()` should be `TypeInfo<double>::TypeInfo()`

Comment: Also, you can't put templates in a cpp file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thanks - that typo was not a typo; it was lacking competence. I have the template *specializations* in the cpp file - that should work?

Comment: The specialization being in a cpp won't work if another translation unit would use it.  All template code should be in a header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make the class constructor a template and be able to specify the template type since you can't call a constructor.

You could make the class a template, and use the template type to get the size of the type instead of having it provided by the user.  That would give you

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeInfo {
    TypeInfo(const std::string& type_name) : 
        type_name(type_name)
    {}

    std::size_t elm_size = sizeof(T);
    std::string type_name;    
};

TypeInfo<double> double_info("double");
TypeInfo<int> int_info("int");
```

Comment: Combined with a helpful comment on my compile error this seems to become the final solution; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify template parameters for a constructor. They can only be deduced. You could send a type tag to your constructor:

```
template<typename> struct tag_t {};
template<typename T> inline constexpr auto tag = tag_t<T>{}; 

struct TypeInfo {
    template<typename T>
    TypeInfo(tag_t<T>) :
        elm_size{sizeof(T)},
        type_name{/* find a way to get name */} {}

    std::size_t elm_size;
    std::string type_name;  
};

TypeInfo double_info{tag<double>};
TypeInfo int_info{tag<int>};
```

You'll have to find a way to get the name of a type from a template argument. Some libraries exists for that like [ctti](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti)

Answer (score 1):

If you're indeed only interested in a handful of fundamental types, and can specialize them manually it seems like a good way to go.

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeInfo; // default values could go here for un-specified types

template <>
struct TypeInfo<int> {
    const std::size_t elm_size = sizeof(T);
    const std::string type_name = "int";
}

// more specializations for double, char and float
```

Then you can go ahead and use it by just instantiating with a template parameter.

If the fact that different instatiations of `TypeInfo`are different types is a problem, you could use a function that return a common `TypeInfo` object with the right values set based on the parameter passed to the function.

```
template <typename T>
TypeInfo get_type_info() {
    return TypeInfo{sizeof(T), "unknown"};
}

template <>
TypeInfo get_type_info<int>() {
    return TypeInfo{sizeof(T), "int"};
}

auto type_info = get_type_info<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a helper function.

```
struct TypeInfo {
    TypeInfo(std::size_t elm_size, const std::string& type_name) : 
        elm_size(elm_size), 
        type_name(type_name)
    {}

    std::size_t elm_size;
    std::string type_name;    
};

template <typename T>
TypeInfo make_TypeInfo(const std::string& type_name)
{
   return TypeInfo(sizeof(T), type_name);
}
```

and use

```
TypeInfo double_info = make_TypeInfo<double>("double");
TypeInfo int_info = make_TypeInfo<int>("int");
```

Comment: Yes - I have considered that